# Fragment as internal class

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

If I declare my fragment as private class, IDE will warn me that it should be public and if I ignore it app will crash at runtime. Question is: why everything works fine if I declare it as internal class? As I understand, fragments should be public to be able to be reinstantiated by Android itself, why it works with my internal classes?

Answer (score 1):

From the JVM's perspective, `internal` classes ***are*** public [within the module](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#modules).